# EF 6 - Will I have issues with different versions of SQL with 2 different environments? 2012 to 2008

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Another developer is using SQL 2012 and the server he will be deploying to has 2008.  For one reason or another, we cant get him to use 2008 and we are not yet ready to upgrade out server(s) to 2012.  There are no real differences that will prevent the sql changes from being deployed to the DB on the 2008 instance, but Im wondering if EF will complain, specifically the data model.  A backup is not able to be deployed onto a older instance, but scripts can be used, so thats not my concern.  Ive just not taken an application using EF that is based on a context pointing to one version of sql, and deployed the application to an environment where the sql instance is a slightly older version.

So I suppose the question is, that provided there are no sql syntax or datatype issues with the underlying sql objects being referenced, should EF 6 handle this situation?  Yes, im going to try it, but are there any technical reasons why it would have issues?

Comment: You could be hit by this http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/12/a-breaking-change-in-entity-framework.html

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns regarding deploying a .NET Entity Framework (EF) application that was developed against a SQL Server 2012 database into a SQL Server 2008 database environment are legitimate. The new app could have problems using the old database server that the developer did not encounter during develpment on the new database server.

However, this potential problem is at best plausible, but not probable. Still, you may want to politely voice your concerns in a cya email.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a [compatability level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) property which is set on a per-database level.  Setting this to lower than the current version will prevent any features being used which were not available at the time.

The highest compatibility level your database should have is 100 (SQL Server 2008/2008R2).

If you set the compatibility level correctly on the database, I would not anticipate any problems with your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that option.